# Kerberos TGT in default session gnome-keyring

Tags: gnome-keyring, kerberos

I am using a 3rd party kerberos kit to authenticate to my work site. In RHEL/CentOS, my ticket is saved into the default session gnome-keyring; yet I am missing something with Ubuntu. When I kinit, the ticket is lost.
However, I can use the command "keyctl session krb5" to create a separate session and it works fine. However, it is now tied to just that single terminal. 
I need a way to export it across my entire session.

Thanks.